# Trouble understanding what is being called and returned

Tags: python

These 2 small codes are giving different outputs..

The only difference that is happening between the 2 codes, is how it is being called. how come their is a huge difference in output?

```
def les():
    key = 100

    def nes():
        nonlocal key
        key += 1000 
        return key 
    return nes

result = les()
print(result)
print(result)
print(result)

#output: 1100,1100,1100 respectively
```

```
def les():
    key = 100

    def nes():
        nonlocal key
        key += 1000 
        return key 
    return nes()

result = les()
print(result())
print(result())
print(result())

#output: 1100,2100,3100 respectively
```

Comment: Add `print(type(result))` to highlight the difference.

Answer (score 6):

In your first example, `les()` calls `nes()`, which returns *an integer*. That integer gets stored to `result`, and does not get changed thereafter. It gets printed three times.

In your second example, `les()` returns *the function `nes`*, which is assigned to `result`. Thereafter, that function is called three times, producing a different integer each time.

When people say python has "first class functions", this is what they're talking about - a function can be passed around just like any other kind of variable.

Comment: Maybe easier to understand:  `nes` get called only once in the first example, it gets called three times in the second example.